# How to align input fields like this? (close and sharing border)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am designing a checkout form and really like how the Stripe checkout forms groups its inputs tightly together as seen [here](https://stripe.com/img/blog/posts/checkout-new-features/blog-post-hero.png)

[image]

I use bootstrap 3 and so far I have marked out the structure, but I havent been able to get the inputs and their borders to be aligned neatly like in the picture

My html

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-grouping">
              <div class="top">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkoutCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number">
              </div>
              <div class="bottom-left">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="checkoutExpiration" id="checkoutExpiration" placeholder="MM/YY">
              </div>
              <div class="bottom-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkoutCVC" placeholder="CVC">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Advice on what? You haven't shown anything useful, like your actual code...

Comment: Well doesn't bootstrap give margin and padding automatically to form elements? So a good place to start is to either override those properties or customize bootstrap. If you really like stripes look why not just look at what they do?

Comment: I'm guessing you will have to add some additional hooks to your inputs that will allow you extend the bootstrap framework. For example, removing the border-radius for only the bottom for any given input.

From there you will have to use some media queries to override how bootstrap handles the positioning. This is going to be some decent customization, bootstrap won't do this right out of the box for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was looking to replicate your example exactly, I would suggest suppressing the default presentation of the input fields (by removing the borders and background) and then wrapping them in divs which you can style as you choose.